# Can I use the default metro apps in Windows 8 with a local account?

Tags: windows-8-preview

I have installed the Windows 8 Release Preview, however I did not connect a Live ID, I am using a Local Account.

I'd like to test out the metro Mail and Calendar apps with my Google account.  The steps to do this according to the interwebs are:

1. Open the Charms sidebar
2. Click Settings
3. Click Accounts
4. Carry on adding accounts

When I open one of these apps, I am presented with a sign-in for Windows Live.  If I click cancel on that, the app closes.  There is no Accounts item in the Settings.

[image: win 8 mail]

I am the only user account on the box, created during the win8 install.  It is listed as an administrator.

Is it possible to use these apps with a Local Account?  I could just create a dummy Live ID, but that just seems silly to me.

Comment: this was one of the most frustrating things I had about Win 8 Developer.

Comment: That's not encouraging...

Comment: I'm very surprised that a Stack Exchange employee would have this sort of question...

Comment: @DragonLord why? We don't know everything! (; (shocking, isn't it?!)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft (annoyingly) provides no official way to do so without first logging in with a Microsoft account.

Unfortunately it looks like you're going to have to bite the bullet and use a Microsoft "proxy" account to get in. But once signed in you can use a Google account for at least `Calendars` and `Mail`.

A burn email address service such as [Mailinator](http://www.mailinator) might be useful.

Comment: I just signed up using my GMail account. What's the problem?

Comment: There is none. Your GMail address  just becomes your `Microsoft Account` address. From the way I understood the OP, she looking for a way to use the Metro App with a `Local Machine` account and not a `Microsoft Account`

Comment: So in order to use a Local Account, I have to have a Microsoft Account.  Or I could just use a Microsoft Account in the first place?  So...the value of a Local Account is crippled?

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff unfortunately yes. it seems like an incentive to use e-mails as Microsoft accounts. (better store tracking? who knows 0:) )